# JDBC  с нуля

Tags: java, jdbc

Здравствуйте, форумчане.

Изучаю java, решил взяться за базы данных. Разработал некоторую теорию, полазил по нете и понял, что зашел в тупик... Если бы кто имел свободную минутку, то был бы очень признателен за помощь в решении следующих вопросов.

1. Как подготовить к работе среду среду разработки Eclipse. Я скачал сервер mysql-5.5.21-win32 и драйвер mysql-connector-java-5.1.18, а что с ними дальше делать, не понимаю.
2. Во всех интернет ресурсах описывается, как законнектиться в базу данных и отправлять в нее запросы. Но я не понимаю, каким образом (с помощью которого кода и библиотек) можно создавать базы данных и таблицы в них, или как можно сделать так, чтобы программа могла добавлять в базу новые таблицы определенной структуры.
3. Можно сделать так, чтобы переноса папки с программой (где также будут драйвер базы данных и сервер) на ос Windows (с установленной java-машиной) было достаточно для корректного функционирования программы и базы данных, проще говоря, чтобы на юзера приходилось минимум настроек - сбросил флешку и пользуется.

Если у кого-то найдется свободная минутка - буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql-5.5.21-win32 инсталлируйте как приложение Windows. Это ваш сервер, который будет управлять одной/несколькими (сколько создадите в общем) БД. mysql-connector-java-5.1.18 - это ваша библиотека для выполнения запросов к БД. Ее нужно подключить к проекту Eclipse как любую другую библиотеку.
Чтобы "создавать базы данных и таблицы в них" возьмите графическое приложение. MySQL клиент под Win. Одно из самых удобных [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) (freeware, portable).

Изучать в pure JDBC особо нечего, это просто драйвер соединения и выполнения запросов к БД. Вам требуется SQL и навык администрирования. Пока вы даже не отличаете клиент от сервера.
Неплохой курс по теории БД [тут](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3913056).

Answer (score 1):

1) Посмотрите набор скринкастов на [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_bV3I5pUOs) - довольно наглядно.

2) JDBC не предназначен для гуйной работы с БД, хотя конечно есть проги которые через JDBC предлагают GUI для работы с JDBC. В том же Eclipse с помощью плагина можно подцепиться и в режиме GUI набрать данные и проч. К сожалентю не очень люблю Eclipse, но что в Netbeans что в Intellij - это делается легко и просто, это да. Если вы имеете ввиду добавление данных программно, то в JDBC с этим проблем нет. Посмотрите на `PreparedStatement` и `Statement.executeUpdate()`

3) Ну насчет мускула не уверен что так можно сделать - все таки кое-какие настройки от машины к машине придется менять (хотя бы адрес сервера). А вот взять какую-нибудь embedded БД то легко и непринужденно - ну скажем Derby или Hypersonic SQL - они как раз для таких штук и предназначены.

Answer (score -1):

посоветовали мне знакомые такой подход:
Среда разработки MyEclipse
и я так понял использовать Microsoft dBase Driver (*. dbf) (и не надо ничего доставлять в Windows?)

```
String url= "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};DBQ="+System.getProperty("user.dir");
Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

public void Con(){
    try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        st = con.createStatement();
    }catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
}
    fCrtCnf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{
                st.executeUpdate("create table "+fCrtNam.getText()+"(Kod integer, q varchar(100), one varchar(100), two varchar(100), three varchar(100), four varchar(100), t integer, img varchar(100));");
            }catch (Exception ex) {System.out.println(ex);}
            fFrmCrt.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

тогда для создания таблицы можно использовать
st.executeUpdate ("create table .....

или исходя из строки Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
папку C:  Program Files  Sun нужно доставлять в винду, или она не используется?
это и есть сервер БД? если да то что нужно доставлять в ОС?
Какие плюсы и минусы могут быть у такого подхода?